# FOSUserBundle extend propel User

Tags: symfony, propel, fosuserbundle

I'm using `FOSUserBundle` and `Propel` in a `Symfony` 2.2 project. I'm trying to extend the `User` class and add a new method to it like so:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Model;

use FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function hasPermission($topic) {
        // TODO check if $topic has permission
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when calling `$this->getUser()` in a controller, the class of the object returned is `FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User`, so `hasPermission()` is undefined.

I tried throwing an exception in the constructor of the custom class and it seemed to be used when registering a new user. But I guess it is not saved as an `Acme\UserBundle\Model\User`.

I tried this with `Doctrine` in another project and it returned the correct class when calling `$this->getUser()`. Am i doing something wrong? How do i make it work with Propel?

**config.yml:**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Model\User
```

**security.yml:**

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed [GlorpenPropelBundle](https://bitbucket.org/glorpen/glorpenpropelbundle), added  a couple of lines to config.yml.

**config.yml**

```
propel:
    classname: Glorpen\Propel\PropelBundle\Connection\EventPropelPDO
    build_properties:
        propel.behavior.event.class:    'vendor.glorpen.propel-bundle.Glorpen.Propel.PropelBundle.Behaviors.EventBehavior'
        propel.behavior.extend.class:   'vendor.glorpen.propel-bundle.Glorpen.Propel.PropelBundle.Behaviors.ExtendBehavior'
        propel.behavior.default:        "event, extend"

glorpen_propel:
    extended_models:
        FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User: Acme\UserBundle\Model\User
```

`$this->getUser()` now returns `Acme\UserBundle\Model\User`.